# KineticJS: Defined object is undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, object, canvas, kineticjs

I'm trying to work with KineticJS and am having trouble with this:

Okay, so at the top area of my JavaScript file, I've got the following little tidbit:

```
var cuin = '';
//...
var cuinShow = new Kinetic.Text({
 x: 320,
 y: 81,
 text: '',
 fontSize: 18,
 fontFamily: 'Lucida Bright',
 fill: 'black'
});
```

And then I have this function:

```
function updateText(){
    cuinShow.setText(cuin);
    return current + getAction() + $.localStorage('difficulty') + " =";
}
```

Upon testing, Chrome tells me it doesn't like my code:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setText' of undefined
```

Now, I know it probably has something to do with the scope of `cuinShow`, but I don't know what. Also, if it means anything (which I don't think it would, but just in case), I have externalized this script along with the KineticJS one.
Here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.storage.js"></script></head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="kinetic-v4.5.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="kgame.js" defer="defer"></script>
</body>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using `window['cuinShow'].setText(cuin);` in your updateText function?

Comment: No, but that didn't fix it either. I did try `stage.get('cuinShow').setText(cuin);`, though, and that gave me this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'setText'`. I'm not sure if that's a step forward or backward.

Comment: Try using `console.log(stage.get('cuinShow'))` and check out the result in the Chrome developer panel to see if it's the object that you're expecting. I would think that this is most likely a scoping issue...but it's hard to say without seeing entire script or having a smaller test case that reproduces it. Can you reproduce it with http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Divey said it's most likely a scope issue.

Look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/gDzC8/)

The function runs fine when you put all of the code you mentioned one after another in the same scope.

My guess is that `var cuinShow` is being declared as a `var` somewhere that isn't accessible to `updateText()`, like inside another function that doesn't include `updateText()`.

Try removing the `var` from your current `cuinShow` declaration and then declaring `var cuinShow` outside at the global scope (or at the top) of your JS file.

**EDIT:**

You defined:

```
var ptext = new Kinetic.Text({
  x: 193.5,
  y: 84,
  text: updateText(),
  fontSize: 18,
  fontFamily: 'Lucida Bright',
  fill: 'black'
});
```

Before defining:

```
var cuinShow = new Kinetic.Text({
  name: 'cuinShowName',
  x: 320,
  y: 81,
  text: '',
  fontSize: 18,
  fontFamily: 'Lucida Bright',
  fill: 'black'
});
```

So updateText() is being called when you declare `ptext`, but cuinShow hasn't been declared yet! This is solved by declaring `cuinShow` before ptext.

Also, your `updateText()` function has some errors:

```
function updateText(){
  console.log(textLayer.get('cuinShow'));
  (textLayer.get('.cuinShowName')).each(setText(cuin));
  return current + getAction() + $.localStorage('difficulty') + " =";
}
```

It should be like this:

```
function updateText(){
  textLayer.get('.cuinShowName').each(function() {
    this.setText(cuin)
  });
  return current + getAction() + $.localStorage('difficulty') + " =";
}
```

`setText()` expects an object before it, so you need to use `this` inside the `each` function.

Comment: I already defined it like that. That's why I'm stumped. Here's a fiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/dxVuP/